# Setup Cassandra in github actions

Tags: cassandra, continuous-integration, github-actions

I need to setup cassandra db in github actions and create keyspace there. How can I achieve that? I tried with actions from marketplace fabasoad/setup-cassandra-action but is given an error.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Comment: You can try to simply run Cassandra as a docker container, using a simple `run:` directive. This way you can also test it locally to see that you got the syntax right, and then place it as an action - https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra

Comment: thank you for answer. but while doing that I came accross problem creating keyspace from github actions. Can you show me how to add keyspace in actions, maybe using run: directive.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: No, I could not create keyspace from github actions.